# How do I select corresponding column field values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have created a data frame as follows -

```
|id    |  Image_name   | result   | classified  |
-------------------------------------------------
|01    |  1.bmp        |  0       |  10         |
|02    |  2.bmp        |  1       |  11         |
|03    |  3.bmp        |  0       |  10         |
|04    |  4.bmp        |  2       |  12         |
```

Now, in my directory I have a folder called images, where I have all the .bmp files stored (1.bmp, 2.bmp, 3.bmp, 4.bmp and so on ).

I am trying to write a script the automatically finds those files in the "Image_name" in the data frame and returns their result and classified values respectively.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import glob
 import os
 data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
 for file in glob.glob("*.bmp"):
     fname = os.path.basename(file)
```

So this was my initial code, I want to find all fnames extracted and then check if the following fname exists in the dataframe and display it with its result and classified columns.

Comment: your initial code is required

Comment: "result and classified values respectively." what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

First get all the images names from the folder and store in a list

```
all_files_names=os.listdir("#path to the dir") 

df.loc[df['Image_name'].isin(all_files_names)]
```

**Output** (assuming all four are there)

```
   id Image_name  result  classified
0   1      1.bmp       0          10
1   2      2.bmp       1          11
2   3      3.bmp       0          10
3   4      4.bmp       2          12
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you just want to access the row where `Image_name` is same as the file, and get the `result` and `classified` columns.

try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
id   |  Image_name   | result   | classified   

01    | 1.bmp         | 0        | 10           

02    | 2.bmp         | 1         |  11         
03    |  3.bmp        |  0        |  10         

04    |  4.bmp        |  2        |  12         
"""), sep=r"\s+\|\s+")

file_example = "2.bmp"

print(df[df['Image_name'] == file_example][["result", "classified"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean masking for this. You can read more about it in below link. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

```
for file_name in df['Image_name']:
    print(df[df['Image_name']== file_name][['result', 'classified']])
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

In case you need the same algo for a lot of images (few thousands/hundred of thousands). It is best to use the column needed for filter as the index of your DataFrame before doing the `.isin()` method in it.

```
image_file_names=os.listdir("#path to the dir")

df = df.set_index(df['Image_name'])

df = df.loc[df.index.isin(image_file_names)]
```

Hope this helps :))